# Need a user ID to stay logged in with GUI mode in windows 2012 Server R2

Tags: windows, windows-server-2012

OS: Windows 2012 Server Standard R2

I've got an admin ID that needs to stay logged in with an active GUI session.  To get to this machine, I need to use RDP.  The ID needs to run a scheduled task with under the ID logged in so it can interact with the desktop.  It's an autoIT script.
I've tried not logging out of RDP, and it eventaully times out, and the script stops working.  If I exit RDP with the ID logged in, it stops working.

I changed the following setting, but the ID is still logging off after a period of time.
Security Settups –Microsoft Network Server –Amount of idle time required before suspending session = 0

Answer (score 1):

The setting had to be enabled via group policy and set values to ‘Never’ for disconnection/log-off. 
Normally preferred values are similar to idle session limit = 3 hrs, end disconnected session = 5 mins

Navigate to the Local Group Policy Editor
Then select "Set Time limit for Disconnected sessions" and under Options: select "Never".
Do the same for the "Log-off" setting.

Comment: An alternative solution would be a virtual machine with a desktop OS.